# Automating Month End Process

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Whether month end process can be automated in progress bases applications like nessie? I already searched for it and I think maybe it can done by scheduling it through background jobs.

Comment: Nessie is an application that has been developed using progress 4gl language and it runs on a Suse Linux server. The users use this to perform business transactions.

Comment: That describes *every* Progress based application.  Who sells it?  To what markets?  What business functions does it encompass?  ("Business transactions" is fairly vague...)  Knowing the answers to these questions might shake loose some additional useful pointers for you.

Answer (score 3):

Scheduling jobs is a function of the OS or of 3rd party applications that specialize in such things (generally used in large enterprises with IT groups that obsess over that kind of stuff).

If you are using UNIX then you want to look into "cron".

If you are using Windows then "scheduled tasks".

In any event you will need to create a "wrapper" script that properly sets  the background job environment and launches a Progress session.  If you are using Windows you should be aware that a batch process is "headless" and that unless your batch process is doing something very strange it will not be using GUI components -- so you should probably run _progres.exe rather than prowin32.exe.

A generic (UNIX) example:

```
#!/bin/sh
#

DLC=/usr/dlc
PATH=$DLC/bin:$PATH

export DLC PATH

_progres -b -db /path/dbname -p batchjob.p > logfile 2>&1 &
```

(That is "_progres" with just 1 "s" -- this is from the days when file names were restricted to 8 characters on some operating systems.)

Windows is very similar:

```
@ echo off

set DLC=c:\progress
set PATH=%DLC%\bin;%PATH%

_progres.exe -b  -db \path\dbname -p batchjob.p > logfile 2>&1
```

But there are a lot of "gotchyas" with Windows.  If, for instance, you run a job using a login-id that might actually login then you will have the problem that on logout all the scheduled tasks will be "helpfully" killed by the OS.  Aside from stopping your job when you probably don't want it to this may have other negative side effects like crashing the db.  To get around that problem on Windows you either create a "service account" that never logs in or use 3rd party scheduler that runs jobs "as a service".

Comment: Thanks Tom.... I am using UNIX and I found that scheduling jobs can be done by crontab -l as you mentioned, but I want to know that for scheduling job like month end process what are file and programs I need to schedule in the backend. Month end procedure is a long procedure with many steps and it is performed at the end of every month so how can I schedule it in the background.

Comment: "How" is via cron with wrapper scripts.  "What" the specific tasks are depends on your application and your business processes.  I have no way to know what those are.  You should talk to the application provider and your users.

Comment: a little worrying to see these type of questions from someone supporting an application on any platform